# Problem with generic sort method with Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I did a generic method to sort both text and dates from my columns, however it does not filter the year, it is ignoring it considering only the month and day. The following method:

orderBy(header) {
let data = [...this.data];

```
  if (this.orderByProperty === header.property) {
    if (this.orderByType === "asc") {
      this.orderByType = "desc";
    } else {
      this.orderByType = "asc";
    }
    data = data.reverse();
    this.$emit("orderBy", data);
    return;
  }

  this.orderByProperty = header.property;
  this.orderByType = header.orderBy;

  switch (header.property) {
    case "active":
      data.sort((a, b) => {
        let comparison = 0;
        if (a[header.property] < b[header.property]) {
          comparison = 1;
        } else if (a[header.property] > b[header.property]) {
          comparison = -1;
        }
        //it has to return -1, 0 or 1
        return comparison;
      });
      break;

    case "name":
      data.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
      });
      break;

    default:
      data.sort((a, b) => {
        let valueA;
        let valueB;
        if (Array.isArray(a[header.property])) {
          valueA = a[header.property].sort()[0];
          valueB = b[header.property].sort()[0];
        } else {
          valueA = a[header.property] || "";
          valueB = b[header.property] || "";
        }

        let comparison = 0;
        if (isNaN(a[header.property])) {
          if (a[header.property] == undefined) {
            comparison = 1;
          } else if (
            a[header.property].length == 10 &&
            this.moment(a[header.property], "DD/MM/YYYY").format(
              "MM/DD/YYYY"
            ) >
              this.moment(b[header.property], "DD/MM/YYYY").format(
                "MM/DD/YYYY"
              )
          ) {
            comparison = 1;
          } else if (
            valueA.toLowerCase() > valueB.toLowerCase() &&
            a[header.property].length != 10
          ) {
            comparison = 1;
          } else {
            comparison = -1;
          }
        } else if (isDateString(valueA)) {
          if (new Date(valueA) < new Date(valueB)) {
            comparison = 1;
          } else {
            comparison = -1;
          }
        } else {
          if (parseInt(a[header.property]) > parseInt(b[header.property])) {
            comparison = 1;
          } else {
            comparison = -1;
          }
        }
        //it has to return -1, 0 or 1
        return comparison
      })
      break
  }

  this.$emit("orderBy", data)
  return
}
```

I tried to change the ordering but it is ordering only by text.
The header sorts both by date and by text.

Comment: When you use `format` method in moment, it will turn your date into a string. Try to compare the actual dates instead of strings.

Comment: I dont know, how i make this?

Comment: `this.moment(a[header.property], "DD/MM/YYYY") >  this.moment(b[header.property], "DD/MM/YYYY")`